# Performance wise, should we favor nested documents or joining over multiple collections

Tags: performance, solr

Performance wise, what is the best option - use nested documents ("_childDocuments") or joins over multiple collections?

Comment: Please see my answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54244434/277023 - Avoid nested documents in Solr

Comment: For performance - flatten your documents.